# A few questions about whatsapp (outside whatsapp)

Tags: android, whatsapp

The first question:

[image: first]
How? How Google Now did that? 
There is an option to send a message from Google Now to Whatsapp, **without clicking on the send button inside Whatsapp**, thats mean there is an intent that doing that, right?

So, my question is, what is that intent? And can I use it in my own app?

The other one:

[image: second]

How can I use "use as" future in my application? (like whatsapp profile photo in this example)

Comment: I don't understand why they down voted this question. I think it as valuable question since applications like [flychat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyperinc.flychat) is also doing the similar things. May be thats the future. I believe this question needs more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do that, see [this](https://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2)

For that we have to use AccountManager class. In our contacts, if our our account was added with whatsapp then it will be possible.

Comment: see also this link, http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.accounts.AccountManager

Comment: I saw, this is an answer to the second question, the first question is How Google Now did that? There is an option to send a message from Google Now to Whatsapp,without clicking on the send button inside Whatsapp, thats mean there is an intent that doing that, right?

So, my question is, what is that intent? And can I use it in my own app?